# Is every conservative, left exact left adjoint comonadic, $\infty$-categorically?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, topos-theory, infinity-topos-theory

Consider a conservative left adjoint $G : C \to D$ between complete 1-categories. By [Beck's theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monadicity+theorem), the following are equivalent:

1. $G$ is comonadic.
2. $G$ preserves $G$-split equalizers.

(2) is generally a bit finicky to check, but there are stronger conditions which can be easier to check and hold sometimes in practice. Following [Barr and Wells](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/12/tr12abs.html), they go by names like "crude monadicity theorem". For example, because equalizers are finite limits, (2) follows from

3. $G$ preserves all finite limits.

Now let $F : A \to B$ be a conservative left adjoint between complete $\infty$-categories. Beck's theorem generalizes in the "obvious" way (I think this is due to Lurie? it's in *Higher Algebra*, and there's another proof due to Riehl and Verity), so that the following are equivalent:

4. $F$ is comonadic.
5. $F$ preserves $F$-split totalizations.

Unfortunately totalizations are not finite limits, so it's not clear that (5) follows from

6. $F$ preserves all finite limits.

This leads to a few

**Questions:**

1. If $F$ is a functor between complete $\infty$-categories which preserves finite limits, then does $F$ preserve $F$-split totalizations?

   A. What if $F$ is additionally assumed to be conservative and / or a left adjoint?

   B. What if $F$ is a conservative left adjoint between presheaf categories, or maybe between $\infty$-toposes, or even between arbitrary presentable $\infty$-categories? Or between presentable stable $\infty$-categories?
2. Alternatively, is there an even *stronger* condition than left exactness which is still weaker than preservation of *all* totalizations, which implies the Beck condition while being easier to check, and which might be frequently satisfied in practice? For instance, when $B$ is $Spaces$, for example, one might imagine asking for preservation of certain limits of towers -- say those satisfying some kind of connectivity hypothesis.

---

My sense is it seems very unlikely that the answer to the first question should be "yes", but I am not at all sure how to build a counterexample. As more hypotheses on $F$ are added, I grow increasingly hopeful that something "magical" might happen and save us.

---

**Motivation:**
The fact that any left exact, conservative left adjoint is comonadic is very convenient in 1-topos theory, because that's the definition of a surjective geometric morphism. It would be nice if there were still just one reasonable choice for the meaning of "surjective $\infty$-geometric morphism".

Another place where left exactness is pretty cheap is when mapping between stable $\infty$-categories (where it already follows from being a left adjoint). A positive answer in this case would mean that the (co)monadicity theorem for stable $\infty$-categories is extremely nice! One would just need to check adjointness + conservativity.

---

**A bit of evidence:**

It's a fact (if finite limits exist) that if a cosimplicial object $X_\bullet$ is split then the associated pro-object $(Tot_{\leq \bullet} X)$ is isomorphic (in the pro-category) to a *constant* pro-object. (I learned this [from Akhil Mathew](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.2156).) If $A_\bullet$ is a cosimplicial object and $FA_\bullet$ is "strongly split" in the sense that the associated pro-object $(Tot_{\leq \bullet} (FA))$ is *literally* constant, then by conservativity and preservation of finite limits, it follows that the pro-object $(Tot_{\leq \bullet} A)$ is also literally constant. It follows that the totalization is preserved in this case.

Of course, for Beck's theorem to kick in, this restricted case will not suffice.

Comment: I asked myself the same question when working on my thesis, indeed this lemma would be key to show that sober infinity-ionads correspond to infinity-topoi with enogh points (Indeed I think it is the only missing thing). See 3.2.6 and 4.0.3 in the ArXiv version of my paper "Towards Higher Topology". While I was thinking about it, I remember I had a negative feeling about it.

Comment: Regarding question (2), here is one possibility. Say that $F : A \to B$ _detects constancy_ if the natural map $A \to Pro(A) \times_{Pro(B)} B$ is essentially surjective. Then if $F$ is a conservative, left exact left adjoint between left exact categories, and if $F$ detects constancy, we may deduce that $F$ is comonadic. (In the pro-categories, it suffices to take just pro-objects coming from $\omega^{op}$-towers.) I don't know how checkable this condition is in practice, nor how often it is satisfied...

Answer (score 4):

The answer is *no*. That is, a conservative, exact left adjoint need not be comonadic, $\infty$-categorically.

For a counterexample, recall Thm 6.7 of Bousfield's [Localization of spectra with respect to homology](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82464212.pdf#page=20), which gives examples of ring spectra $E$ such that $L_E (H\mathbb Z) \to Tot(H\mathbb Z \wedge E^{\wedge \bullet+1})$ is not an equivalence. In the adjunction $E \wedge (-) : Spectra_E {}^\to_\leftarrow Mod_E : Forget$, the left adjoint is conservative and exact. If it were comonadic, then the totalization of that cosimplicial object (which is $E \wedge (-)$-split) would be canonically equivalent to $L_E(H\mathbb Z)$. Since it isn't, the adjunction is not comonadic.

(Here, $L_E : Spectra \to Spectra_E$ is the (homological) Bousfield localization with respect to $E$, and $Mod_E$ is $E$-modules).

So the moral of the story is that the failure of the $\infty$-categorical crude monadicity theorem lies in the difference between Bousfield localization and nilpotent completion.

It's conceivable that crude comonadicity might be rescued by restricting attention to $\infty$-topoi, but given the pervasiveness of these counterexamples of Bousfield, that seems unlikely to me.